# Addslashes displays as forward slashes in php

Tags: php, escaping

I have a file on my server that i want to access. The filename is `ken\'s book.doc`

But in my db, it was stored as `ken's book.doc`

(I have fixed the backslash issue, but still have problems accessing the previously uploaded files on server.

I used addslashes to add the back slash but it displays it as: `ken/'s book.doc` (that is a forward slash instead of a backslash.

I have used:

```
str_replace("'", "\'", $filename);
```

yet it displays as a forward slash.

How can i fix this?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Extra Information: I am using the new value as part of a link. that is:

```
<a href="<?php echo str_replace("'", "\'", $filename);?>">View</a>
```

Comment: What platform and php version are you using?

Comment: The file name is `"ken\'s book.doc"`? I somehow doubt that. Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: yeah, the original filename is ken's book.doc, it seems magic quotes was on and it added the slashes

Comment: @Tomalak Filenames can apparently contain backslashes on unix filesystems, but probably needs to be quoted. [See Reference.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words) @Ogugua If `str_replace("'", "\'", $filename);` returns a string with a forward slash then `$filename` must have contained a forward slash to begin with.

Comment: @Tomalak , am sure there is no forward slash. @Ancide, pls added an extra info in my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a filename that contains a backslash on disk, I would fix that first. Your second problem was appearantly not using [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) when storing that filename into the database (why it ended up there without backslash).

[`addslashes`](http://php.net/addslashes) btw does not add forward slashes by itself. That part of your story is untrue. And to remove them again you wouldn't need the quirky [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) call, but just [`stripslashes`](http://php.net/stripslashes).

The actual problem (after your edit) turns out to be a html link. That's simply because browsers have the habit of turning backslashes into forward slashes in urls. To prevent that apply [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode)

```
 <a href="<?=urlencode(stripslashes($filename));?>">View</a>
```

Comment: i think while retrieving data from database it removes slashes that were formerly added. I used addslashes so i can have same filename with file on disk. It did add the slashes but the actual problem is what you pointed out in your last paragraph

Comment: The database does not remove backslashes *while* retrieving. That happens while inserting. For inserting stuff into the DB it needs to be properly escaped.

Comment: urlencode does not solve my problem. it added more funny characters. please is their any other option?

Comment: Additionally [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars). Otherwise it's some other circumstance that you didn't let on.

Comment: @Ogugua @mario Try `rawurlencode()` instead of `urlencode()`. `urlencode()` converts _spaces_ to '+' which browsers seem not to like (in the actual URL). `rawurlencode()` converts _spaces_ to %20 which is OK.