# How to stripslashes from the names of file on server with php

Tags: php, file, escaping

Sequel to my question here: [Addslashes displays as forward slashes in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324144/addslashes-displays-as-forward-slashes-in-php/6324382#6324382) ,

I want to strip slashes from the filenames of files i have on my server. the slashes were added during file upload (magic_quotes).

Please how can i go about this? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<?php
$path         =  '/path/to/files/dir/';
$file_types   =  'txt,doc,pdf';

foreach (glob($path.'*.{'.$file_types.'}', GLOB_BRACE) as $filename){
    if(rename($filename , stripslashes($filename))){
        echo 'Renamed file from '.$filename.' to '.stripslashes($filename).'<br />';
    } else{
        echo 'Failed to rename file from '.$filename.' to '.stripslashes($filename).'<br />';
    }
}
?>
```

Change path to files and the comma separated list of file types.

#### Update with asker's code on the comments:

```
$dir='cv'; 
if(is_dir($dir)){ 
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) { 
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($dh))) { 
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") { 
                $file2 = $dir."/".$file; $newfile=$dir."/".stripslashes(urldecode($file)); 
                if(rename($file2, $newfile)){
                    echo "renamed from $file2 to $newfile <br>";
                } else{
                    echo "error renaming from $file2 to $newfile <br>";
                } 
            } 
        } 
        closedir($dh); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: am yet to understand why your code did not work. It all displayed renamed, but on server the names were still same.

Comment: i eventually did this and it worked: $dir='cv';
 if (is_dir($dir)) 
 {
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
   
   while (false !== ($file = readdir($dh))) 
   {
    if ($file != "." && $file != "..") 
    {
     $file2 = $dir."/".$file; $newfile=$dir."/".stripslashes(urldecode($file));
     if(rename($file2, $newfile)){echo "renamed from $file2 to $newfile <br>";}else{echo "error renaming from $file2 to $newfile <br>";}
     
    }
      }

   closedir($dh);
  }
 }

Comment: Maybe you didn't enter the right directory name there. Based on your comment it should have been `$path = '/cv/'`. But whatever worked for you is good. I will update my answer with your code.

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/function.stripslashes